# Interpolating at midpoints with quadratic splines

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let $\Pi$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with points $x_0,\dots,x_n$. If $s\in C^1[a,b]$ and on every subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ $s$ is a quadratic spline with the following interpolation knots,
$$s(z_i)=y_i,\quad  (z_i)=\frac{(x_{i-1}+x_i)}{2} \quad i=1,\dots,n$$
and $$s(x_0)=y_0 \quad s(x_n)=y_{n+1}.$$ Give a way of calculating the the splines $s_i$.

I tried using $s(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and plugging in
$$s(x_i)=ax_i^2+bx_i+c,~s(x_{i-1})=ax_{x-i}^2+bx_{i-1}+c$$
and similarly for $z_i$
$$s(z_i)=a\frac{(x_{i-1}-x_i)^2}{4}+b\frac{(x_{i-1}+x_i)}{2}+c$$
not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It looks like you defined a bunch of notation, showed some work but didn't actually ask a question?

Comment: sorry my bad lol

Answer (score 1):

You need a different $a,b,c$ for each spline segment. Call these $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$. Then, the equations you wrote down form a linear system. You can solve to get the $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$. The system is banded, so it's easy to solve.